# python subargparser with additional parameters and help message

Tags: python, argparse

I have a cli program where I need to pass in additional parameter based on the name of the subcommand. I got this so far, but it doesn't have a help message for different name that got passed in.

```
def route_handler(args, remain):
   perform_common_tasks()
   if args.name == 'A':
      route_a_handler(remain)
   elif args.name == 'B':
      route_b_handler(remain)


main_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
subparsers = main_parser.add_subparsers(title='sub-commands', required=True)

subparser_a = subparsers.add_parser('route')
subparser_a.add_argument('--name', '-n')

subparser_a.set_defaults(func=route_handler)
args, remain = main_parser.parse_known_args()
args.func(args, remain)
```

---

```
usage: open.py route [-h] [--name {A,B}]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --name {A,B}, -n {A,B}
abc@MacBook-Air python % python3 open.py route A -h
usage: open.py route [-h] [--name {A,B}]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --name {A,B}, -n {A,B}
```

How do I add help message for route A or B?

I've tried adding subparser for subparser_a, it does give me a nice help message. But I'm no longer able to call route_handler to perform the common tasks and dispatch based on the route name.

Comment: Typically when `setdefaults` is used with subparsers, each parser gets a different `func` value.  That func is then called with the `args`, e.g. `args.func(args)`.  `args` in such a case will have different attributes based on the argument defined for the subparser.  The subparser `help` does not display that `args.func` value.

Comment: Looks like your `name` has a `choices`, `subparser_a.add_argument('--name', '-n', choices=['A','B'])`.  You don't show what `remain` is, not that it helps with the help.  Anyways you are call `func` right.  But the `help` knows nothing about that.  It displays info for the defined `arguments`.  It does nothing with other attributes set with `set_defaults`.